# Replacing text in a filename in Google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to copy a file and rename it at the same time.  My script searches through the directory for all the relevant files, copies and then renames them.  I can copy them into a different directory or with appending something to the name, but I cannot find how to replace part of the text in the name with other text.

I have tried replace and replaceText, neither seem to change the filename but rather look at the contents of the file.  In the code below I want to save the filename into FileRenameStart and then replace Oldmonth with NewMonth but I just cannot find the right way to do it it.  Anyone able to help?

Thanks

```
    function newMonthFunction() {

  // what files we want
 var OldMonth = "July 2016";
 var NewMonth = "August 2016";
 var FindThisText = "Core " + OldMonth;
 files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "' + FindThisText + '"  and mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"');
 var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "' + FindThisText + '" and mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"');

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file);
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId());
    var FileRenameStart =file.getName();
    var FileRenameend =FileRenameStart
    DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId()).makeCopy(FileRenameEnd)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close to resolve this issue. It should work for you:

```
function newMonthFunction() {
  var OldMonth = "July 2016";
  var NewMonth = "August 2016";
  var FindThisText = "Core " + OldMonth;
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "' + FindThisText + '" and mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"');

  while( files.hasNext()){
    //getting the old file
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(files.next().getId());
    //getting the old filename and replacing the old month by the new one
    var newName = file.getName().replace(OldMonth,NewMonth);
    //copying the old file using a new name for copy
    var newFile = file.makeCopy(newName);
    //logging the new filename
    Logger.log(newFile);
  }
}
```